how to prevent community toolkit properties being changed based on some condition
I want to rewrite one property using the Community Toolkit but it's not working if I need to put one condition before it is changed and return it
earlier it was written like this
public double Height
{
    get { return GetValue<double>(nameof(Height)); }
    set
    {
        double oldValue = GetValue<double>(nameof(Height));
        if (IsValueApproxSame(value, oldValue))
            return;

        SetValue(nameof(Height), value);
        _messenger.Send(new ContainerElementActualSizeChanged(ElementId));
    }
}
    

so in this, if the new value is approx the same I want the property not to change, now in the community toolkit I tried this approach which is not working it's updating it to newValue even if I return it in Changing method
[ObservableProperty]
double height;
partial void OnHeightChanging(double oldValue, double newValue)
{
    if (IsValueApproxSame(newValue, oldValue))
        return;
}
partial void OnHeightChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
{
    _messenger.Send(new ContainerElementActualSizeChanged(ElementId));
}


It is not possible to cancel a property change by means of the OnXyzChanging method, which may become more clear when you look at the generated code in the example in the Running code upon changes section of the documentation. In general, return; as the last statement in a void method is of course always redundant.

@Clemens Yeah I have checked the generated code, but how can I achieve this condition in Community toolkit?

By not using the ObservableProperty attribute and an implementation with ObservableObject's SetProperty method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject
